# Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'kotlin-android-extensions' not found

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0, kotlin-android-extensions

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'.
```

When i add this extensions in android studio preview, give me this error
"Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'kotlin-android-extensions' not found.".

My build gradle

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mohamed_elbaz.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Show your build.gradle.

Comment: kotlin-android-extensions is not supported anymore use [viewbinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)

Answer (score 84):

The build.gradle snippet you posted looks like the config inside your app module. What does the build.gradle in your project's root directory look like? To add the kotlin plugin dependencies it should look something like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta6'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The important part being the line `classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"`which adds the kotlin plugins.

Comment: You can find what is the latest kotlin plugin version here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin

Answer (score 67):

> To use the plugin, you have to add it in your root build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: You can find what is the latest kotlin plugin version here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio we can fix it in following ways:_

Using the plugins Domain Specific Language (DSL) in **App Level Graddle**:

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions" version "1.4.21"
}
```

That's all to fix it.

But if you're using legacy plugin application, then add the following in **App Level Gradle**:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.21"
  }
}

apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions"
```

Hopefully, it'll be helpful!

Comment: You can find the latest kotlin plugin version here: plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin

Answer (score 2):

**put the below lines in build.gradle app**

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
         apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

**and also do changes in build gradle by adding kotlin extension and path**
//put the ext above the dependency line//

```
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.31'
 dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: You can find the latest kotlin plugin version here: plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

in Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1

build.gradle Project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.0' apply false
id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.3.14" apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.10' apply false // add
}
```

build.gradle app:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
android {
....

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

}
dependencies {
 implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
}
```