# Not able to use kotlin library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, android-library

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/Yalantis/Multi-Selection) library for my app but as it is made in kotlin I am facing the problem . I downloaded the module of this library and imported this module in the project but in the initial state i am gettin kotlin plugin not found so i changed the gradel as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101908/error1-0-plugin-with-id-kotlin-android-extensions-not-found)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    resourcePrefix "yal_ms_"
}
buidscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.1-2'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.1-2'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

I am trying to use the kotlin library for the first time and I dont know any thing much about kotlin any advice how to use this library will be helpful .

Comment: You could start with using the current _Kotlin_ version. Also it's not clear what your error is about. Kotlin Plugin could also refer to the AS plugin for _Kotlin_. You should always make sure to use the latest version of AS. If this is the case it might be possible that the plugin crashed, so have a look at the error log.

Comment: Hey can you answer my flutter question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Importing [this](https://github.com/Yalantis/Multi-Selection) library by gradle

Add  `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to the repositories of project gradle. So it will be like this

**build.gradle(Project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and add `compile 'com.github.yalantis:multi-selection:v0.1'` to dependencies in **build.gradle(app)**

This may create Manifest Merge Conflicts error while building project to remove that add  **tools:replace="android:label"** under `<application>` tag in Manifest