# Jenkins - Could not find method api()

Tags: android, jenkins, kotlin

I'm implementing CI process with my project using Jenkins tool.
Seems that there's compile issue when using kotlin, here's my console output for the build:

```
What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':TestProject'.

Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.
```

ANDROID_HOME is set where the jenkins runs.

***EDIT 1:***

the issue fixed when i added 'ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'' to the buildscript.

Now the build fails because of dependency declaration:

> What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred evaluating project ':TestProject'.
>
> Could not find method api() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I'm declaring my dependencies with api annotation, since it's a submodule:

```
api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$android_support_version"
```

Jenkins won't recognise the api method

Comment: Sounds like you've forgot to add `kotlin-gradle-plugin` to your dependencies in the project `build.gradle` file (i.e. one level above the `app` directory).

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46101908/error1-0-plugin-with-id-kotlin-android-extensions-not-found

Comment: @Michael you are right, since it's a submodule i thought it would be redundant but it was necessary